# Capture an image by non-default device

Tags: image, video

Guys!

I need capture video from certain webcam which isn't `$DefaultImagingDevice`. As I know there is one legal way:
`ImageCapture["Device"->$ImagingDevices[[x]]]` where x is number of needed device. However ImageCapture doesn't allow to make a grid on the image like this:

```
grid = Graphics[{Gray,
    Table[Line[{{(i - 1)*16, 0}, {(i - 1)*16, 240}}], {i, 1, 21}],
    Table[Line[{{0, (i - 1)*16}, {320, (i - 1)*16}}], {i, 1, 16}]
    }];

Dynamic[Show[
  CurrentImage[],
  grid,
  ImageSize -> 800]]
```

[image: http://s18.postimg.org/hek0gtp2h/Camera_small.jpg]

May be somebody knows how to apply CurrentImage for certain non-default imaging device? Or how to take just image without any interface elements using ImageCapture?

Comment: Perhaps something in here may help `?ImageAcquisition'CaptureDump'*`

Comment: Could you extend your proposition please? What is ?ImageAcquisition'CaptureDump'*  ????

Comment: Evaluate this in your front end Information["ImageAcquisition`CaptureDump`*"]

Comment: Where I can find more info about this ImageAqcquisition?

Comment: Does `Block[{$DefaultImagingDevice = $ImagingDevices[[x]]]}, code here]` work? Sorry, got no imaging devices to test with.

Comment: It seems that I've solved my problem now. There is non-documented comands:

`IMAQ``StopCamera[]`
`IMAQ``StartCamera[]`

They could be used with an option 

`"Device" -> $ImagingDevices[[x]]`

So, if you have dynamic object with `CurrentImage`, these will start/stop capturing at required device..

Comment: Simon's code work too.
Thanks for all for your help!

Comment: Update. Simon's code doesn't work. It was post-effect of my command with above mentioned option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So basically `ImageCapture[]` is the hub where you set things which `CurrentImage[]` adoptes. Run `ImageCapture[]` and **in-interface** select the device - it is easier:

[image]

Then run your code with `CurrentImage[]` - it will now pick up the external camera.

[image]

Droste video-feedback effect you see in the images proves I'm not using my laptop camera in all this ;-) - not that we need any proof - just an excuse to mention Douglas Hofstadter. Let me know if you get the joke.

Comment: That would have worth a `GIF` ;o)